# c++ binary_search function trouble with sorted array (popular names search)

Tags: c++, vector, binary-search

Below is my code and the text files (ignore commented out lines). I'm having trouble getting the binary search method to work correctly. I have a sorted vector. I even have a for statement to print out the checks used in the binary search method and the checks inside the for loop and the print statement says it should be returning true. Thanks for any help! Tips/improvements on other parts of the code is also appreciated thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector<string> getVector(const string&);
string getName(const string&);
void selectionSort(vector<string>&);
bool search(const string&, const vector<string>&);


int main()
{
    string boyName, girlName;
    bool boyNameFound, girlNameFound;  
    vector<string> boyNames(getVector("BoyNames.txt"));   
    vector<string> girlNames(getVector("GirlNames.txt"));
    
     /* debugging 
    
   for (vector<string>::const_iterator i = boyNames.begin(); i != boyNames.end(); ++i)
    {
        cout << *i << endl;
    }
    for (vector<string>::const_iterator i = girlNames.begin(); i != girlNames.end(); ++i)
    {
        cout << *i << endl;
    }
    
    */
    
    boyName = getName("boy's");             //getting the name of a boy and setting the var boyName = to it
    //girlName = getName("girl's");
   
    selectionSort(boyNames);                //sort vector of popular boys names
    
    //selectionSort(girlNames);
    //boyNameFound = search(boyName, boyNames);    
    //girlNameFound = search(girlName, girlNames);
    
    if(search(boyName, boyNames)){ cout << "boys true " <<endl;}
    else{cout << "boys false"; }
   // if(search(girlName, girlNames)){ cout << "girls true " <<endl;}
   // else{cout << "girls false";}
   
    
   
    
}

vector<string> getVector(const string& ph){
    vector<string> names;
    ifstream namesFile(ph.c_str());
    if (!namesFile){
        cout << "Error opening file \n";
    }
    string line;
    while(getline(namesFile,line)){
        names.push_back(line);
        
    }
    names.push_back("end");             //to help when searching for names
    return names;
        
}
    
    
    
string getName(const string& ph){
    string name;
    if(ph=="boy's"){    //when boys is selected
        cout << "Enter a boys name or N to skip: ";
        cin >> name;
        
    }
    else{               //when girls is selected
        cout << "Enter a girls name or N to skip: ";
        cin >> name;
    }
    return name;
}




bool search(const string& ph, const vector<string> &nameList){
    bool nameInList;
    cout << "The boys name we are searching for is " << ph <<endl;              //printing out the name we are looking for. this is for debugging
    
    cout << "TEST BINARY SEARCH: 0=false 1=true: " << binary_search (nameList.begin(), nameList.end(), ph) << endl;
    if(binary_search (nameList.begin(), nameList.end(), ph)){
        nameInList = true;
    }
    
    for(int y = 0; y < nameList.size(); y++)
    {
        cout << ph << " == " << nameList[y] << endl; //printing out for debugging
        if (ph == nameList[y])
            nameInList = true;

    }
    
    
    
    return nameInList;
}
    
    
void selectionSort(vector<string> &arr){                                        //selection sort works good
    int startScan, minIndex;
    string minValue;
    for (startScan = 0; startScan < (arr.size() - 1); startScan++){
        minIndex = startScan;     
        minValue = arr[startScan];
        for(int index = startScan + 1; index < arr.size(); index++){
            if (arr[index] < minValue){            
                minValue = arr[index];            
                minIndex = index;         
            }
        }
        arr[minIndex] = arr[startScan];      
        arr[startScan] = minValue;
    }
}
```

**TEXT FILE: BoysNames.txt**

```
Jacob
Michael
Joshua
Matthew
Daniel
Christopher
Andrew
Ethan
Joseph
William
Anthony
David
Alexander
Nicholas
Ryan
Tyler
James
John
Jonathan
Noah
Brandon
Christian
Dylan
Samuel
Benjamin
Zachary
Nathan
Logan
Justin
Gabriel
Jose
Austin
Kevin
Elijah
Caleb
Robert
Thomas
Jordan
Cameron
Jack
Hunter
Jackson
Angel
Isaiah
Evan
Isaac
Mason
Luke
Jason
Gavin
Jayden
Aaron
Connor
Aiden
Aidan
Kyle
Juan
Charles
Luis
Adam
Lucas
Brian
Eric
Adrian
Nathaniel
Sean
Alex
Carlos
Bryan
Ian
Owen
Jesus
Landon
Julian
Chase
Cole
Diego
Jeremiah
Steven
Sebastian
Xavier
Timothy
Carter
Wyatt
Brayden
Blake
Hayden
Devin
Cody
Richard
Seth
Dominic
Jaden
Antonio
Miguel
Liam
Patrick
Carson
Jesse
Tristan
Alejandro
Henry
Victor
Trevor
Bryce
Jake
Riley
Colin
JaredJeremyMarkCadenGarrettParkerMarcusVincentKalebKadenBradyColtonKennethJoelOscarJosiahJorgeCooperAshtonTannerEduardoPaulEdwardIvanPrestonMaxwellAlanLeviStephenGrantNicolasOmarDakotaAlexisGeorgeCollinEliSpencerGageMaxCristianRicardoDerekMicahBrodyFranciscoNolanAydenDaltonShanePeterDamianJeffreyBrendan
TravisFernandoPeytonConnerAndresJavierGiovanniShawnBradenJonahCesarBradleyEmmanuelManuelEdgarErikMarioEdwinJohnathanDevonErickWesleyOliverTrentonHectorMalachiJalenRaymondGregoryAbrahamEliasLeonardoSergioDonovanColbyMarcoBrysonMartin
```

Comment: Did you test your sorting routine for two names,  say Adam & Ben, and then for Ben & Adam?

Comment: The part starting with JaredJeremyMar... and ending with ...rcoBrysonMartin looks like a single line of text. I'm  not sure that's what you intended.

Comment: We can assume, that `binary_search` works as expected. So I would guess, that the sorting function is the culprit.

Comment: Im almost 100% sure the sorting function works fine. Directly before the call to binary search i print out the sorted vector and it looks fine/sorted to me.

Comment: Also if you guys look below the binary sort i have a for loop that is looping through the vector checking for the provided name manually that also fails to work correctly

Comment: The line and comment `names.push_back("end"); //to help when searching for names` does not make sense. It make the code harder as you have to deal with that special case in all functions in addition to the normal handling which is still required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that `binary search` only works on a sorted list. It starts with two variables `l` and `r`, which represent the left and right bounds that the `name` being searched for must lie between.

At each step, it creates a variable `m = (l + r)/2` and compares the name at that index to the one being searched for. If the name is the one you're looking for, you're done. Otherwise if the name is *greater*, then set `r` to `m` and continue; and set `l` to `m` in the case that it is smaller.

Here is my code:

```
int binarySearch(const vector <string> &names, string name){
    int l = 0, r = names.size();
    while(l != r){
        int m = (l+r)/2;
    
        if(names[m] == name){return m;}
        else if(names[m] > name){r = m;}
        else{
            l = m;
        }
    }

    return -1; // name does not exist in the list
}
```

An alternative way to implement binary search is to implement it using *jumps*. This approach keeps one variable, `curr`, that represents the index being compared at the moment.

```
int curr = 0;
for(int i = names.size()/2; i >= 1; i /= 2){ // jump size
    while(curr+i < names.size() && names[curr+i] <= name){
        curr += i;
    }
}

if(names[curr] == name){
    // name was found at index curr
}
```

Both of these approaches center around the same idea, and their runtimes are pretty much identical. Using either one of these approaches should work for your program.

Your program also has a function `selectionSort()`, which I'm assuming is supposed to sort the `std::vector` before you execute a binary search algorithm. Note that C++ provides a general-use sorting function, `std::sort()`, which will run much quicker than selection sort in many cases. To use `std::sort()`, you must have typed `#include <algorithm>` somewhere in your program.

Comment: Your [binary search code](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62842065/1) seems to return `-1`. Always. Because there is only one return statement in it: `return -1;`

Comment: You're right. I'll modify my code to return the correct value.

Comment: Also, while your at it, capture the vector as a const reference, the copy is O(N), the function is O(logN)

Comment: Well done, +1. People will opine on your return m; formatting.

Comment: I tried implementing both of your solutions neither seem to work. The 2nd solution you offered seems to never enter the if statement.

Comment: I deleted my selection sort and used the built in std::sort function

Comment: The second solution should *always* enter the if-statement. The only way it wouldn't enter is if the vector in which it is searching is empty. Can you send a link to your whole file?

Comment: Do you have a cloud9 account by chance?

Comment: Uh, no. You could use onlinegdb.com instead.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/Hy8xYoUJw sorry for the late response and thank you for your continued help friend!

Comment: Not exactly sure what I changed but things seem to be working now thanks for the help guys especially you Telescope!